# How to write days and kilometres

Tags: java

A traveler does every day for several kilometers. The  task is to create a method that displays his path from the beginning of the journey (it looks as follows:"Day # 1: 10km; Day # 2: 7km; Day # 3: 13km;"). The method should work for any number of days of travel.

I wrote the  followiong code, but  it works  only for 5 days:
`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the number of the day:\n");
    int day = in.nextInt();     
    String  distance = null;


    switch(day){
    case 1: 
        distance = "10 km";
        break;
    case 2:
        distance = "7 km";
        break;
    case 3:
        distance = "13 km";
        break;
    case 4:
        distance = "11 km";
        break;
    case 5:     
        System.out.println("distance ="+9+ "km");
        break;
    default:
            for(int i =0; i>distance.charAt(i); i++){   
            System.out.println("distance ="+i); 
            }
        break;          
    }
        System.out.println(distance);
    }
```

`
Would  you  be  so  kind to  help me  to  write  code for differend days.
For  instance, during the 17th day he goes 8 km.
How to  write this program without switch and cases.
Many thanks  in  advance

Comment: is there any kind of formula how the distance is calculated?

Comment: Looks like random distances. So you might want to use a generator to get random distances and add them up?

Comment: I think you will answer the question yourself when you grasp how the distances are calculated. It does not seem to me a programming doubt, but you clearly did not understand the functional problem you have on your hands!

Comment: How *should* this work? How do you come up with distances beyond 5 days? Or do you just repeat the same distances?

Comment: What should the result be on day 6? 10 km again?

Answer (score 0):

If we don't know how you get those numbers, we can't really help, but what you could do is use a Map.

Let's say your man can walk up to 50 km a day. You could use:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> walks = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    int nbDays = 20; //number of days he'll walk
    int maxKmPerDay = 50;


    // This fills up your map with distances and days
    Random r = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < nbDays; i++) {
        walks.put(i, r.nextInt(maxKmPerDay ));
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < nbDays; i++) {
        System.out.println("Distance = " + walks.get(i) + " km.");
    }
}
```

If you don't have to save the values or do calculations with them, you can skip the Map part and directly print:

```
System.out.println("Distance = " + r.nextInt(50) + " km.");
```

Comment: Thank you for  your  help very  much

Comment: @Vit No problem, that's the purpose of the site :)
If that answered your question, feel free to mark it as the accepted answer, so the question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

One *possible* solution (if you want him to repeat the same distances over and over again) (and please excuse my use of C# here as I'm not sitting in front of a Java IDE; the Java should be very similar though):

```
private static void Distances()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the day:");
        int day;

        // Keep prompting the user until they enter a valid integer
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
        }

        String distance = null;

        // Use modular arithmetic to determine
        int multipleOf5 = day % 5;

        switch (multipleOf5)
        {
            // Even multiple of 5
            case 0:
                distance = "9 km";
                break;
            // E.g.: day 6 should be 10 km again
            case 1:
                distance = "10 km";
                break;
            case 2:
                distance = "7 km";
                break;
            case 3:
                distance = "13 km";
                break;
            case 4:
                distance = "11 km";
                break;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(distance);
    }
```

In this case, day 6, for example, would have the same distance as day 1 (as would, for example, day 11). Similarly, day 7 would have the same distance as day 2.

If it really is completely random and you don't care about it being consistent about subsequent calls, you only need to generate some random number each time - you don't even care what the user input is. It's just a random number no matter what.

```
Random r = new Random();
// He walks some distance from, for example, 5 km to 30 km
int distance = r.Next(5, 30);
Console.WriteLine(distance + " km");
```

It becomes slightly more complicated if you want this to be. In that case, you'd want to store the result in a Hash Table:

```
// Build a hash table
    private static Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();

    // In C#, you must use the same instance of Random across all callsdue to the fact that
    // the pseudorandom number generator is seeded by time
    private static void DistanceCached(Random r)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the number of the day:");
        int day;

        // Keep prompting the user until they enter a valid integer
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out day))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid integer");
        }

        // Generate a value for this day if we haven't yet
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(day))
        {
            dict[day] = r.Next(5, 30);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(dict[day] + " km");
    }
```

If you wanted to get *really* sophisticated, you could serialize this and deserialize this so it's consistent across multiple calls of the program.